# When I install facebook application my custom facebook app fails to log in

Tags: android, facebook

My code launches a facebook login screen when the Facebook Mobile application is uninstalled. I fill out my username and password and it all works fine. However, when I do install the facebook application from Facebook. My application pops a window that asks for permission to get basic_info and friends list but then I fail to log in.  The status is CLOSED_LOGIN_FAILED.  Here is my code.  What am I doing wrong?

```
public class FacebookHome extends CustomActivity {
private Session.StatusCallback statusCallback = new SessionStatusCallback();
private UiLifecycleHelper uiLifecycleHelper;
private static final String TAG = "Facebook";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.facebook_home);
    addListenerForView(R.id.facebook_home_layout);
    uiLifecycleHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(this, statusCallback);
    uiLifecycleHelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 

}

private void onSessionStateChange(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
    if (state.isOpened()) {
        loggingTextView.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.facebook_logout));
        Log.i(TAG, "Logged in...");
    } else if (state.isClosed()) {
        loggingTextView.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.facebook_login));
        Log.i(TAG, "Logged out...");
    }
}

protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    if (session != null &&
           (session.isOpened() || session.isClosed()) ) {
        onSessionStateChange(session, session.getState(), null);
    }

    uiLifecycleHelper.onResume();
}

@Override
protected void nonVerboseIntroduction(){
    speak("Facebook Main menu");
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    uiLifecycleHelper.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy(){
    super.onDestroy();
    uiLifecycleHelper.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    uiLifecycleHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    uiLifecycleHelper.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
public void confirmation(int selectedViewID) {
    switch (selectedViewID) {

    case R.id.facebook_login:
        //This corresponds with a login button on my custom layout
        TextView view = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.facebook_login);
        if (view.getText().toString().matches(getResources().getString(R.string.facebook_login))) {
            login();
        } else if (view.getText().toString().matches(getResources().getString(R.string.facebook_logout))) 
            exitSession();
        break;
    }
}


private class SessionStatusCallback implements Session.StatusCallback {
    @Override
    public void call(Session session, SessionState state,
            Exception exception) {
        onSessionStateChange(session, state, exception);
    }
}

private void login() {
    try {
        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
        if (session == null) {
            session = new Session(this);
            Session.setActiveSession(session);
            session.openForRead(new Session.OpenRequest(this)
                    .setPermissions("basic_info")
                    .setCallback(statusCallback));
        } else {
            if (!session.isOpened() && !session.isClosed()) {
                session.openForRead(new Session.OpenRequest(this)
                        .setCallback(statusCallback));
            } else {
                Session.openActiveSession(this, true, statusCallback);
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.toString());
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to register your app on developer.facebook.com console if you have yet not done this go to apps tab and select create new app, fill in the necessary credentials.

Why most of the people encounter this problem is because of wrong hash key provided at facebook dashboard

use the following code from Facebook developer's guide to generate the hash key and add it to your app details, then it will start working for your Facebook id particularly.

```
 try {
    PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
            "com.facebook.samples.hellofacebook", 
            PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
    for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
        md.update(signature.toByteArray());
        Log.d("KeyHash:", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
        }
} catch (NameNotFoundException e) {

} catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {

}
```

To make it work for any Facebook id you need to make the app and all its feature live from status and review option in dash tab of your app.

Answer (score 0):

Have you configured your native app settings in the facebook app. If not, then update your native app settings with your apps package name and key hash. Then you will be able to login via Native facebook app.

Comment: If everything is ok, then it should work. I would recommend you to again recheck the facebook app configuration.